# How can I share data with a concern in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am attempting to use Rails Concerns (or even a bare Module mixin) to share methods across some of my models.

Given a simple model, I am storing some encoded data in one of the 
fields:

```
class DataElement < ActiveRecord::Base
    include EmbeddedData

    ENCODED = %w(aliases)
end
```

I’ve then made a concern with the needed methods for managing the data:

```
module EmbeddedData
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        after_find :decode_fields
        before_save :encode_fields

        @decoded = {}
    end

    def decoded(key, value = false)
        @decoded[key][:value] if @decoded.has_key? key
    end


    def decode_fields
        @decoded = {} if @decoded.nil?
        ENCODED.each do |field|
            if attributes[field]
                @decoded[field] = {
                    value: JSON.parse(attributes[field]),
                    dirty: false
                }
            end
        end
    end

    def encode_fields
        ENCODED.each do |field|
            if decoded[field] && decoded[field][:dirty]
                attributes[field] = @decoded[field][:value].to_json
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Given this setup, I get the error `uninitialized constant EmbeddedData::ENCODED`

If I change the reference to self::ENCODED in the Concern I get the error:
    # is not a class/module

I've even tried making a method on the concern `register_fields` that I can then call from the model, but the model just throws an unknown method error.

Running out of ideas here and looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the way to access the class constant is:

`self.class::ENCODED`